# VB.NET Created an instance of a form that contains a web browser ~ how do I access the document completed on the new instance?

Tags: vb.net, browser

I have create a form with a web browser on it. I create an instance of that form that contains web browser.

how can I edit the web browser document completed on the new instance?

Thanks

-EDIT

What I am doing is creating a form that has all the elements on it that I want in an object. A webbrowser, button, etc.

I am creating an instance of that form which is creating an object. From what I read whenever you create an instance of an object you also call create an instance of all it's items like web browser.

I am able to set the navigation of the web browser on the new form but I don't have access to the web browser completed section of the new form.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Do you mean how do you handle the document completed event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how to associate an event handler to the specific webbrowser istance in your brand new form, set the webbrowser as PUBLIC in the designer, and then you will be able to see the instance, therefore all its events and properties as well.  Note that you have to reside on the same Thread that created the form to access the webBrowser, so you may have to 1) create a thread, 2) let that thread istantiate the Form (with a public webbrowser in it), 3) access the webbrowser form that same thread to set the handler for the DocumentCompleted event.

If this is not matching with your intention, please re-phrase the shole question as it is a little hard to understand your aim.

Cheers